# How to make a square block in a rectangular parent?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Block `.cell2` contains block `.round-area`.

Block `.round-area` is not square.

But I need to make `.round-area` a square.

I also need the height of block `.cell2` to equal the height of the block `.round-area`

The result should look like this:

[image: this]

```css
html, 
body{
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.cells{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: stretch;
    justify-content: space-between;  
    height: 100%;
}

.cell{
  width: calc(33.3% - 10px);
  height: calc(33.3% - 10px);
  background: red;
  margin: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.cell:nth-child(1) {
  width: 30%;
}
.cell:nth-child(2) {
  width: 60%;
}

.round-area{
  background: orange;
  /*border-radius: 50%;*/
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="cells">
  <div class="cell">cell</div>
  <div class="cell cell2">
     <div class="round-area">
      content
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">cell</div>
  <div class="cell">cell</div>
  <div class="cell">cell</div>
  <div class="cell">cell</div>
  <div class="cell">cell</div>
  <div class="cell">cell</div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/zlodiak/0w5ykbw7/9/)

Answer (score 1):

I have answer to your question.

I used jQuery for this:

```
var height= $('.round-area').height();
$('.round-area').css({
    'width': cw + 'px'
});
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MaciejWojcik/n6DAu/2708/)

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done *properly* using CSS alone.

With that being said, would this trick be an option, where an image is used, hidden, to keep it a square?

```css
html, 
body{
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.cells{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: stretch;
    justify-content: space-between;  
    height: 100%;
}

.cell{
  width: calc(33.3% - 10px);
  height: calc(33.3% - 10px);
  background: red;
  margin: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.cell:nth-child(1) {
  width: 30%;
}
.cell:nth-child(2) {
  width: 60%;
  text-align: right;
}

.round-area{
  position: relative;
  background: orange;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
}
.round-area img {
  height: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.round-area-abs{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="cells">
  <div class="cell">cell</div>
  <div class="cell cell2">
     <div class="round-area">
       <img src="http://placehold.it/50" alt="">
       <div class="round-area-abs">
        content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">cell</div>
  <div class="cell">cell</div>
  <div class="cell">cell</div>
  <div class="cell">cell</div>
  <div class="cell">cell</div>
  <div class="cell">cell</div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
</div>
```

---

Even if the above does keep its ratio, I recommend using script to keep your markup clean.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
  keepRatioWidth(document.querySelector('.round-area'));
})
window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
  keepRatioWidth(document.querySelector('.round-area'));
})

function keepRatioWidth(el) {
  el.style.width = el.getBoundingClientRect().height + 'px';
}
```

```css
html, 
body{
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.cells{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: stretch;
    justify-content: space-between;  
    height: 100%;
}

.cell{
  width: calc(33.3% - 10px);
  height: calc(33.3% - 10px);
  background: red;
  margin: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.cell:nth-child(1) {
  width: 30%;
}
.cell:nth-child(2) {
  width: 60%;
}

.round-area{
  background: orange;
  /*border-radius: 50%;*/
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="cells">
  <div class="cell">cell</div>
  <div class="cell cell2">
     <div class="round-area">
      content
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">cell</div>
  <div class="cell">cell</div>
  <div class="cell">cell</div>
  <div class="cell">cell</div>
  <div class="cell">cell</div>
  <div class="cell">cell</div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Down voter, please comment on what is wrong or misunderstanding, or else no one is able to adjust to make their answer better